# Draw horizontal line up to rounded rectangle node in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have a rounded rectangle node, and I want to draw a horizontal line up to it. I can use things like `(A.210) to (A.210 -| -2, 0)`, but I want to be able to specify the y-coordinate explicitly, and I'm struggling to see a way to do that (short of doing trigonometry by hand to figure out the right angle anchor).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) [draw, rounded rectangle, minimum height=4em] {};
  \draw (-2, -1em) to (A); % I want this line to be horizontal.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width=0.5pt,color=red] (-2,0-1em) -- (0,0-1em);
    \draw[line width=0.5pt] (0,0) circle (2em);
    \fill[color=white] (0,0) circle (2em);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the line width and the color to whatever you want. **Note that color in `\fill` must be set as your paper background color to hide the unnecessary part of the red line.**

Comment: I need a `node[rounded rectangle]` (contents were cut for the MWE), but this is close enough to get me on the right lines of drawing the shape over the line.

Comment: @dutchie, try this: `\draw (-2, -1em) to (0,-1em);\node (A) [draw,fill=white, rounded rectangle, minimum height=4em] {};`

Answer (score 3):

You could also use intersections for that (in case you put the A node on top of some background, which prevents you from filling it white).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) [draw, rounded rectangle, minimum height=4em,name path=A] {};
  \path[name path=B] (-2, -1em) coordinate (aux) -- (0,-1em);
  \draw[red,name intersections={of=A and B}] (aux) -- (intersection-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like the "right" way to do it, awesome! I'll have to do some more reading about the intersections library.